# First row not recognized as column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnheader

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("14_5.csv")

print(df.head())
```

```
              Price,Date,Ticker
             104.0,2016-07-01,A
104.87815067615534,2016-07-05,A
104.41190933506331,2016-07-06,A
104.93195657145004,2016-07-07,A
104.42127356374375,2016-07-08,A
```

When I add:

```
prices = df.Price
```

to the code, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Price'
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to save each column as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`skipinitialspace=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) tells `pd.read_csv` to skip spaces after delimiter.
Notice the difference it makes to the column labels:

```
In [165]: pd.read_csv('14_5.csv').columns.tolist()
Out[165]: ['              Price', 'Date', 'Ticker']

In [167]: pd.read_csv('14_5.csv', skipinitialspace=True).columns.tolist()
Out[167]: ['Price', 'Date', 'Ticker']
```

The reason why you were getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Price'`
is because the column label was being set to `'              Price'`. So you would have had to access the column with `df['              Price']`.

If you use

```
df = pd.read_csv('14_5.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

then you can access the first column with `df['Price']`.